# mono.exe is not a valid Win32 application (WindowsXP)

Tags: c#, installation, mono

I downloaded and installed Mono 3.12.1 (only the framework, not the IDE) under Windows XP. The setup was finished successfully.

Then I tried to compile the following source code for test reasons:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Mono World");
    }
}
```

I clicked the icon "Open Mono Command Prompt" in the start menu and then used the command "mcs hello.cs".
The problem is that the process terminates with the error message "mono.exe is not a valid Win32 application" which popups and the output "Access denied" on the console.

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Mono has dropped WindowsXP support some releases ago.

It shouldn't come as a surprise because WindowsXP is an OS which doesn't receive support from Microsoft anymore, so if you run it in production you're open to security issues (as it doesn't receive updates).

From a [thread on the mono-dev mailing list](https://mono.github.io/mail-archives/mono-devel-list/2015-April/042889.html):

> I checked [download page](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/) and
>   installed previous older version which is `mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe`

For the longer version of the story, read [the full thread in the mono-devel mailing list](https://mono.github.io/mail-archives/mono-devel-list/2015-April/042889.html), and [this pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1723).

*Note:* If you wish to install MonoDevelop on Windows XP, it is worth noting that [Gtk# Version 2.12.22](https://www.npackd.org/p/gtksharp/2.12.22) is the minimum required for MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio [5.0.1.x](https://www.npackd.org/p/monodevelop/5.0.1.3) (latest version which will run on XP). Gtk# 2.12.26 will also install, but no guarantees as to whether it works. All of these can be downloaded from the [Npackd site](https://www.npackd.org/). Install the Gtk# update after the mono framework. Then install Monodevelop.

Comment: @altralaser Mono v3.12.0 produces same result despite [its release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/) stating "The minimum version support of Windows is now WinXP SP2 ...".

Comment: @user4157124 Mono 3.2.3 and Gtk# 2.12.22 are the latest versions that will work on XP. Trust me; I've tried later versions. They don't work reliably.